# How do you cancel a jQuery fadeOut() once it has started?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic div element to represent a message that I show for a few seconds and then fade it out using

```
$('#message').fadeOut(5000);
```

I want to be able to cancel the fade out if the user hovers their mouse over the div.

How can I cancel the fade out **once the fadeOut method has started to fade the div?**

My existing code, below, works if the mouse enters the div whilst it is being shown but I need to allow for if the user hovers over the div once it has started to fade.

```
$('#message').mouseenter(function() {
  clearTimeout(this.timeout);
});
$('#message').mouseleave(function() {
  this.timeout = setTimeout("$('#message').fadeOut(5000)", 3000);
});
$('#message').fadeIn(2000, function() {
  this.timeout = setTimeout("$('#message').fadeOut(3000)", 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Check out the stop function

http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/stop#clearQueuegotoEnd

Comment: nice!  using stop, this gets yo back to normal for the mouseenter function:

$(this).stop().animate({opacity:'100'});

Comment: I can't believe I didn't spot that one in the jQuery docs! It must be a Monday. Thanks.

Comment: Specifically, @daddywoodland's .stop().animate({opacity:'100'}) combo is what allows any fadIn/fadeOut to restart based on your trigger. Works great.

Comment: This link no longer works and is the reason that links alone are not allowed on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 27):

Also, you can test if an element is in the middle of an animation using the [`:animated`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/animated) selector:

```
$('#message').mouseover(
    function () {
      if($(this).is(':animated')) {
         $(this).stop().animate({opacity:'100'});
      }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, merely using `stop()` didn't work (at least in Firefox), after searching I figured out that It should be `stop(true, true)`:

```
$('#message').mouseover(
    function () {
         $(this).stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    }
);
```

> stop(): Stops the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

or even you can use `finish()` instead:

```
$('#message').mouseover(
    function () {
         $(this).finish().fadeOut();
    }
);
```

but there is a side effect about finish(), it stops all other running animations too.

> finish(): Stops the currently-running animation, remove all queued animations, and complete all animations for the matched elements.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27485982/4344976).

Comment: `.finish()` did the trick to `fadeIn()` and element after issued a `fadeOut()` on in.