# restart jquery.fadeOut() while it's fading out

Tags: jquery

I'd like to have a jquery fadeOut() restart whilst it's in the middle of fading out.

I have the following statement

```
$('#status').html('<div style="padding:5px; margin:0 0 0 200px;"><img src="/images/done.png" /> ' + message + '</div>').show().fadeOut(2000);
```

When a user performs an action, this statement gets run.
for the 2 seconds it's running, the user can perform another action which calls this statement.

At the moment, the fadeOut has to complete before the fadeOut animation will play again.

Is there a way to make the fadeOut simply restart from the beginning again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.stop()` before calling `.fadeOut()`.

Optionally, use `.stop(true, true)` if you want it to start from the destination values.

Comment: thanks :D  i had to make a slight modification. I had to call $('#status').stop(true, true); BEFORE running the status statement

Answer (score 1):

You can call [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before calling fadeOut. That will restart the fadeOut animation. Otherwise, the second fadeOut will be queued after the first one.

Answer (score 1):

[How do you cancel a jQuery fadeOut() once it has began?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421298/how-do-you-cancel-a-jquery-fadeout-once-it-has-began)

In short, call the **[.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)** method.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
jQuery.stop().fadeOut()
```

to prevent queueing up the fadeOut Animation.

```
.stop() can be used to prevent queueing any jQuery Animation
```

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, but in my case better way was

```
//onclick 
  .stop(true, true).fadeIn().stop(true, true); //reset: stop old fadeOut and make visible again
  .fadeOut(); //again
```