# Reset fade to opacity defined in css

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a problem stopping the jQuery `fadeOut` effect and have it return to the correct opacity as specified in the css file.

When the mouse enters an `.item`, the `.editing` div shows up immediately with an opacity of 90% as defined in the css. Now, when the mouse leaves and re-enters during fadeout, the opacity is stuck at the current fadeout opacity level. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QShwJ/)

All I can find is that you should call `opacity(100)` after calling `stop()`. See this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421298/how-do-you-cancel-a-jquery-fadeout-once-it-has-began). The problem is that this doesn't work for me, because I want to reset it to the 90% as defined in the css.

Anyone knows how to do this without hardcoding the correct opacity in javascript?

**HTML**

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="item"><div class="editing">edit</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="editing">edit</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="editing">edit</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="editing">edit</div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.editing {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".item").hover(function() {
    // enter
    $(".editing", this).stop();
    $(".editing", this).show();
}, function() {
    // leave
    $(".editing", this).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QShwJ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to set the `jumpToEnd` parameter, do it like this:

```
$(".item").hover(function() {
    // enter
    $(".editing", this).stop(true, true).show();
}, function() {
    // leave
    $(".editing", this).fadeOut(500);
});
```

See here for reference:
http://api.jquery.com/stop/#stop-clearQueue-jumpToEnd

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/QShwJ/2/